# javascript & html - how to delete a check box

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I basically just posted a question related to this task so I apologize if it seems really repetitive but I ran into another problem.

So basically I'm creating a program that allows the user to create and manage a ‘to-do list’ by getting the user to add and remove items. Currently if the user enters something in the textbox and clicks the add button, a new checkbox is made. I'm trying to get it so that the user can also remove checkboxes/items by checking a box and clicking the remove button. I tried writing a program in an attempt to do the above, but when I went to run it in my html browser, it didn't do anything and I'm not sure why.

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Checklist</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><h1>My to-do list</h1></div><br />
        <div id ="myCheckList">Enter an item:</div>
        <div>Type something: <input type="text" id="textbox"></input></div>
        <input type="button" id="addBut" value = "Add item" onclick="addItem()"/>
        <input type="button" id="removeBut" value =  "Remove items" onclick="removeItem()"/>
        <input type="button" id="toggleBut" value = "Toggle highlight" onclick="toggle()"/>
        <input type="button" id="sortBut" value = "Sort items" onclick="sort()"/>

        <script src="addHandler.js"></script>
        <div id="checklist_items"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function addItem() {
    var input = document.getElementById("textbox");
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("checklist_items");
    if(input.value.trim() != "") {
        var new_element = document.createElement("DIV");
        new_element.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox"> '+input.value;
        wrapper.appendChild(new_element);
    }
    else {
        alert("You must enter at least 1 character.");
    }
}


function removeItem(){
    if (document.getElementById('checklist_items').checked){
        ("checklist_items").remove();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're checking if the containing div `checklist_items` is checked, but you need to check if the *input* it contains is checked.

Comment: what is $, in line $("checklist_items").remove(), jQuery, are you including jQuery in html?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to check the *checked* property of the parent div (*#checklist_items*) which does not have that property (*checked*) at all.

You can to target all the checked checkbox inside the *checklist_items* using [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then loop through them to remove the *parentNode* of the current item.

```js
function addItem() {
    var input = document.getElementById("textbox");
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("checklist_items");
    if(input.value.trim() != "") {
        var new_element = document.createElement("DIV");
        new_element.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox"> '+input.value;
        wrapper.appendChild(new_element);
    }
    else {
        alert("You must enter at least 1 character.");
    }
}


function removeItem(){
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('#checklist_items input:checked');
  list.forEach(function(chk){
    chk.parentNode.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<div><h1>My to-do list</h1></div><br />
<div id ="myCheckList">Enter an item:</div>
<div>Type something: <input type="text" id="textbox"></input></div>
<input type="button" id="addBut" value = "Add item" onclick="addItem()"/>
<input type="button" id="removeBut" value =  "Remove items" onclick="removeItem()"/>
<input type="button" id="toggleBut" value = "Toggle highlight" onclick="toggle()"/>
<input type="button" id="sortBut" value = "Sort items" onclick="sort()"/>

<script src="addHandler.js"></script>
<div id="checklist_items"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of all the inputs inside that div and check if they are checked or not and if they are checked you can remove both the div and the input

```js
function addItem() {
    var input = document.getElementById("textbox");
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("checklist_items");
    if(input.value.trim() != "") {
        var new_element = document.createElement("DIV");
        new_element.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox"> '+input.value;
        wrapper.appendChild(new_element);
    }
    else {
        alert("You must enter at least 1 character.");
    }
}


function removeItem(){
var ele=document.querySelector('#checklist_items').querySelectorAll('div')
    for(let i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
    {
    if(ele[i].querySelector('input').checked)
    {
   ele[i].querySelector('input').parentNode.removeChild(ele[i].querySelector('input'));
    ele[i].parentNode.removeChild(ele[i])
}
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Checklist</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><h1>My to-do list</h1></div><br />
        <div id ="myCheckList">Enter an item:</div>
        <div>Type something: <input type="text" id="textbox"></input></div>
        <input type="button" id="addBut" value = "Add item" onclick="addItem()"/>
        <input type="button" id="removeBut" value =  "Remove items" onclick="removeItem()"/>
        <input type="button" id="toggleBut" value = "Toggle highlight" onclick="toggle()"/>
        <input type="button" id="sortBut" value = "Sort items" onclick="sort()"/>

        <script src="addHandler.js"></script>
        <div id="checklist_items"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    You need to add an unique Id based when you add check box
var i=0; 
function addItem() {
    i=i+1;
    var input = document.getElementById("textbox");
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("checklist_items");
    if(input.value.trim() != "") {
        var new_element = document.createElement("DIV");
        new_element .setAttribute("id", "add"+i);
        new_element.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" onclick="setRemoveableList(i)"> '+input.value;
        wrapper.appendChild(new_element);
    }
    else{
        alert("You must enter at least 1 character.");
    }
}
var removeList=[];
function setRemoveableList(val){
    removeList.push(val);
}

function removeItem(){
      for(var j=0;j<removeList.length;j++){
        var cuurrId='add'+removeList[j];
         var rm= document.getElementById(cuurrId);
        return rm.parentNode.removeChild(rm);
         //either you can hide the div by $("#"+cuurrId).hide()

        }
    }
```